# Django ModelForm label customization

Tags: python, django, label, django-forms

The Django documentation explains how to use labels customization in a ModelForm model map here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/.
However, when I try to follow it I get the error:

```
name '_' is not defined.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, why there should be a `_` symbol before the parenthesis?

Here is my code:

```
class RuleForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.css_class = "rule"

    class Meta:
        model = Rule
        fields = ("user", "title")
        exclude = ("user")
        widgets = {
            "title" : TextInput(attrs={"class" : "title"}),
        }
        labels = {
            "title": _("Rule Title"),
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you import following?

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

`ugettext`, `ugettext_lazy` are used to specify translation strings. `_` is used to save typings.

See [Translation | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/).

Comment: It does get rid of the error message, but it still shows the default title, rather than the one I specified. In fact I do not need any translators here, I might just do: labels = {"title": "Rule Title",}, but it still gives me the default title rather than "Rule Title".

Comment: @GregoryR, Make sure you're using Django 1.6+. `labels` option was added in Django 1.6. See [Creating forms from models | Django documentation - Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: @GregoryR, BTW, `super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` should be `super(RuleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. `exclude = ("user")` -> `exclude = ("user",)` or `exclude = ["user"]`.

Comment: @GregoryR, `("user")` is a string, not a tuple.

Comment: Yeah, I have Django 1.5.1, that's the problem.

Answer (score 27):

If somebody else are looking for it at this time
(2016 - Django 1.9)

It works just like this for me:

```
labels = {
            "title": "Rule Title",
            "other_field": "Other Title"
        }
```

With out the lazy import.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, with or without the lazy import.

Answer (score 2):

I have Django 1.6 and I have the SAME problems as 'GregoryR'.  I didn't try importing _ugettext_lazy as _.  Instead, I did this the easy way (last line):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.css_class = "rule"
    self.fields['title'].label = 'Rule Title' <-----
```